# Do the Shiro tags 'isLoggedIn' and 'authenticated' mean the same thing?

Tags: grails, shiro

I am just getting started with both Grails and Shiro and I am looking at adding Shiro to an existing project.

I am wondering if the Shiro tags `isLoggedIn` and `authenticated` mean the same thing (i.e. always produce the same result)?

The [Grails Shiro Plugin page](http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro) seems to suggest so:

> The tags `<shiro:isLoggedIn>` and `<shiro:authenticated>` check for an authenticated user, the tag `<shiro:user>` checks for a known user (authenticated or remembered) and the tag `<shiro:remembered>` checks only for a remembered user.

But it is hardly an in-depth description and it doesn't explain why they both exist if they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are exactly the same.  [Here is the source code](https://github.com/pledbrook/grails-shiro/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/apache/shiro/grails/ShiroTagLib.groovy):

```
/**
 * This tag only writes its body to the output if the current user
 * is logged in.
 */
 def isLoggedIn = { attrs, body ->
    if (checkAuthenticated()) {
        out << body()
    }
}

/**
 * A synonym for 'isLoggedIn'. This is the same name as used by
 * the standard Shiro tag library.
 */
def authenticated = isLoggedIn
```